# JavaScript variable in EL expression

Tags: javascript, el

In my servlet I'm sending many values back to JSP page by *for* cycle like this:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    for (int i = 0; i < veryBigNumber; i++){  
        if (something){  
            request.setAttribute("value" + i, "true");  
        else{  
            request.setAttribute("value" + i, "false");  
    }  
}
```

And in JSP I would like to read them in the same way with JavaScript and EL:

```
<script>  
    for (var i=0; i < veryBigNumber; i++){  
        if ("${value + (i)}" == "true"){  
            doSomething;  
        } else{  
            doSomethingElse;   
    }  
}  
</sctipt>
```

The problem is I don't know how to make the variable *i* a part of EL expression. Is it possible? And if yes, how?
Thanks...

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I thought I would say this: This question was downvoted to -1. However, these kinds of conceptual misunderstandings are extremely common in the world of coding. And it might be extremely hard to find answers to questions like this, because it is a conceptual misunderstanding. I do not think these deserve to be downvoted. I have a bit of experience with jsp, but have had a break from it for a while, and wondered the exact same thing. This question, and it's answer, was extremelt helpful to me, even if it only reminded me of something I really already knew.

Answer (score 2):

You're making a conceptual mistake here. Java/JSP/EL runs on webserver and produces HTML/CSS/JS which in turn runs in webbrowser (rightclick page in webbrowser and do *View Source* to see it yourself). Yet you're expecting that EL and JS runs in sync in the webbrowser. This is not true.

You basically need to perform the iteration and EL evaluation using JSP instead and write it accordingly so that it prints the proper JS code you want.

```xml
<script>
    <c:forEach begin="0" end="${veryBigNumber - 1}" var="i">
        <c:set var="value" value="value${i}" />
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${requestScope[value]}">
                doSomething;
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                doSomethingElse;   
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
</script>
```

Note that this particular construct is clumsy and a code smell. The concrete functional requirement is not exactly clear, so it's not possible to propose the more elegant solution for whatever you're trying to achieve.