# How to use a JavaScript variable in an EL expression

Tags: javascript, el

I am trying to archive very simple things but I'm not getting the expected result from the below script. I don't know what im going wrong.

```
<script>      
        var APP = "APPR";// in properties file APPR = Approved
        var message = "#{props["APP"]}";// JSF EL expression with resourcebundle 
        alert(message)// Want to print "Approved" but its printing ??APP???
</script>
```

Im using JSF resourcebundle and javascript.

Comment: try this: `var message = "#{props['"+ APP + "']}";`

Comment: Thanks Napster, I already tried this but im getting error "EL Expression Unbalanced: ... #{props['"+ APP + "']}";"

Comment: What about this: #{props[APP]}";?

Comment: Use single quotes when dealing with Maps and similar expressions.

Comment: @Rapster it's printing blank

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript variable in el expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786167/javascript-variable-in-el-expression)

Comment: @JasperdeVries no duplicate variable in EL expression. I have only 3 line javascript code.

Comment: Other duplicate could be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575128/passing-localized-javascript-messages-from-resource-bundles-using-jsf

Comment: Thanks BalusC/Jasper- I tried with above solution but no luck.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, I'm not using JSP I'm using JSF and tried with your code snippets but didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below

```
#{props['"+ APP + "']}
```