# SpEL Map get value by dynamic key name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, el

Sorry my English is poor. I have a question.

In JavaScript , I can get value like this code:
console.log("${testMap['0']}"); //return 'some string';

When I change my code like this ,I can't get value...
let status = '0';
console.log("${testMap['" + status  + "']}");//return '';

how can I get Map value by dynamic attribute key in JavaScript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript variable in EL expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786167/javascript-variable-in-el-expression)

Comment: Doesn't look like this has something to do with Spring: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions. Please, be careful when you chose tags for your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask